# Using dd to copy an img file to an SD card

Tags: filesystem, sd-card, dd, raspberrypi

I am trying to copy an img file into an SD card in order to use in a Raspberry Pi.

I use the instruction:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/path/to/my/image.img of=/dev/sdb1
```

Where sdb1 is my SD card which I previously formatted using gparted into FAT32 filesystem.

However after `dd` finishes, if I access the sd card it just shows filenames with non-ASCII characters, even the information about the files seem corrupt (filesize, modification date, etc...)

If I run gparted again it showns now that the filesystem is unknown (previously was correctly formatted as FAT32 and accessible).

**PD**: I already tried to copy different images, in different SD cards and even in different computers, so I might be doing something wrong.

**PD2**: I also tried to run `dd` with `bs=1M` with the same results.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You aren't understanding what dd does. The resulting file system will always be the one from the image.  Your image.img is likely corrupt

Comment: Your command directly writes to the partition, it makes no sense to format it before letting `dd` write to it as every file system structure will get overwritten. Try mounting your image and verify it is in good shape. The SD card partition will be an exact, full clone of your image after running the command.

Comment: Maybe you should be writing to /dev/sdb, the disk instead of a partition sdb1.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify:

```
of=/dev/sdb
```

That is, use just `sdb`, not `sdb1`.